# Extract: error writing to file qgis-bin.exe

Tags: qgis, installation, windows

I have been facing problem during the installation process. The installation is getting aborted by showing this error message. Since this happened with 2.18 version, I tried with 2.16.3 version. Even then i am getting the same message. Please help me in overcoming this problem. [image]

Comment: Do you have at least 2 GB free disk space? And maybe you need admin rights to install software.

Comment: It asked for 1.4GB space for installation. I have 1.7GB.

Comment: My current installation occupies 1.55 GB. 1.7GB free space might be too small, if the installer requires some additional temporary space for extracting.